# Tables width 100% in IE causes problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a disturbing problem with tables in IE ... 
I created a Joomla! Template combined with bootstrap. 
The customer created the content of the joomla! website.

You can find my problem here: 
(link removed)

When you look at it in Firefox or other browsers you can see that everything is fine. 
But when you look at it in Internet Explorer (I hate that browser), you can see, that the tables with the grey background are not shown correctly. They have to much width. Texts are cut off.

I tried a lot things and tested different solutions from the Internet. But I can't find a solution for that.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing?

Comment: agreed that is quite odd. One thing I would say is that using tables in that way (ie for page layout) is not considered good practice these days. I'd suggest using more semantic markup for it; it'll improve your SEO. That would likely get rid of the issue as a side effect, though it would obviously be more work than a simple fix to what you've got.

Comment: this one has been bugging me so I've been picking at it to see if I can find the problem. I still haven't got an answer, but I would recommend doing some basic validation. Loading the page in IE results in several javascript errors being shown in the console. Some of them are fairly obvious, and should be fixed. Also I note that you're using an XHTML doctype, but you have a number of errors in the markup. You should use the W3C Validator to find and fix the errors, especially since you're using XHTML, which can be less forgiving than HTML.

Comment: w3c validator - see http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wolfvision.com%2Fvisualizer25%2Findex.php%2Fen%2Fdownload%2Fconnectivity-software&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by your large image at the bottom (connectivity2_big-photo.jpg). While you've set the height and width on the image, the CSS has the height and width set to 'auto' which is pushing the dimensions to a maximum possible size in IE.

Either use an appropriately sized image or remove width:auto and height:auto from the img declaration and everything works again.

I suspect this has more to do with using XHTML 1.0 Transitional: IE's reverting to 1997, but that's what you're asking for!

Comment: +1. Can't believe I missed that. Also, you'd be well advised to have the site provide the image at the size you want displayed rather than a bigger version and asking the browser to scale it. If you'd done that, the problem would never have happened. Also images scaled in the browser often don't look as good as they could do, plus you're making the user download a bigger file than they need to.

Comment: BIG THANKS to ceeb! I have tried a lot of things but never realized that the image at the bottom is to big ... i also can't believe that I have missed that ... 
Now everythings is OK ... so easy ...

@ Spudley
I know the code and the tables are horror. But that's a CMS System and my customer creates it's contens by his own. He oftens works with tables and to big pictures ... thats often a problem.